# How do I fix the width of bootstrap navbar on a tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what it looks like on my tablet:

[image: result]

When I inspect remotely in chrome, I see that the body width(600px) is not that of the document, being set by a div with a min-width:1000px;.

How can i get the bootstrap navbar to fill the full width?

You can access the website [suphearst.ca](http://www.suphearst.ca)

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

the solution is too simple

just add min-width:1000px; to body

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are missing the viewport meta tag in your html document. It will fix your problem and render the document after the device scale.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)